# Why is my server using a well known port as source port

Tags: linux, port, traffic

Is it normal that my server is requesting 8.8.8.8 dns with 22/udp as source port? How can i get it to use unregistered ports only

Comment: Could you add to the question the output of:
`lsb_release -a` , 
`cat /etc/resolv.conf`
and `resolvectl status` ?

Comment: I ll post it as soon as i can thanks

Comment: None of these commands work for me. I'm on rhel 7.

Comment: I expect `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to work for RHEL7. Could you share the error message?

Comment: search xxxx.pp
nameserver 8.8.8.8        no problem. Only that command is not recognised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it normal that my server is requesting dns with 22/udp as source port?

No.

You would expect DNS queries from a client to use either:

- a random ephemeral port (which you can adjust in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` but is typically 32769-60999)
- when no port randomization is used: UDP port 53

Comment: Thank you HermanB ill check the referenced file

Comment: Port range is specified to ephemeral ports